# Redshift: Construct a cumulative sum over a variable date range

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I'm struggling to build a query that dynamically constructs a cumulative sum using a date range.

To put the question metaphorically, I'm looking to calculate the average number of room service plates ordered per guest by day. Take the following example dataset:

| guest_id | most_recent_plate_ordered_date | cumulative_plates_ordered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/1/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 10/2/2020 | 2 |
| 1 | 10/4/2020 | 3 |
| 2 | 10/1/2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 10/2/2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 10/3/2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 10/4/2020 | 2 |

This is the desired output I'm trying to achieve:

| date | cumulative_plates_ordered | number_of_people |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2020 | 2 | 2 |
| 10/2/2020 | 3 | 2 |
| 10/3/2020 | 4 | 3 |
| 10/4/2020 | 6 | 3 |

In essence, I need to build two figures: the sum of the maximum number of plates ordered per person and the number of people per day. I've generated the number of people per day—that was pretty easy. Where I'm struggling is building a query that can dynamically sum as the date range expands.

I was able to generate the query that gives me the desired number for a given date max. My problem is translating this into something that generates this number across all possible dates in one query. Here's an example query for a range from 10/1 to 10/1:

```
select sum(max_cumulative_plates_ordered) from (
  select guest_id, max(cumulative_plates_ordered) as max_cumulative_plates_ordered
  from raw_data
  where most_recent_plate_ordered_date <= '2020-10-01'
  group by 1
)
```

Any thoughts? It feels like such an easy question to struggle with.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  2020-10-04 has only two rows.  Why is the value "3"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want:

- The number of *distinct* people who have ordered up to a particular day.
- The sum of the maximum number of `cumulative_plates_ordered` order on that day.

However, this suggests that the value on 2020-10-03 is really 4 not 5.

One method is correlated subqueries:

```
select dte::date,
       (select count(distinct guest_id)
        from t
        where t.most_recent_place_ordered <= gs.dte
       ) as num_guests,
       (select sum(plates)
        from (select t.guest_id, max(t.cumulative_plates_ordered) as plates
              from t
              where most_recent_place_ordered <= gs.dte
              group by t.guest_id
             ) t
       ) as num_plates
from (select distinct most_recent_place_ordered as dte from t) gs;
```

What makes your data challenging is the cumulative sum.  You can use `lag()` to get the change on a particular day.  With that data, it is much simpler to get the results you want using window functions and aggregation:

```
with net as (
     select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by guest_id order by most_recent_place_ordered) as seqnum,
            cumulative_plates_ordered - coalesce(lag(cumulative_plates_ordered) over (partition by guest_id order by most_recent_place_ordered), 0) as new_plates
      from t
     )
select most_recent_place_ordered,
       sum(sum( (seqnum = 1)::int )) over (order by most_recent_place_ordered rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as num_guests,
       sum(sum( new_plates )) over (order by most_recent_place_ordered rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as num_plates
from net
group by most_recent_place_ordered
order by most_recent_place_ordered;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=edbca413745da9fa6229883a9050126a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for this! I tested these queries in my client and got the following errors, respectively:

1. Error in SQL: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet
2. Error in SQL: Default parameter not be supported for window function lag

I'm running in a redshift instance!

Comment: @HannaHaddad . . . Ah, yes.  I updated the second query to be more Redshift compatible.

Comment: This works perfectly! So basically the logic is that in the net statement, you create 1. a flag that will all us to pick the first record per person and 2. a flag that uses the lag function to identify where a new plate is added. Then it just becomes a simple cumulative sum by datecanvassed. Right?

Comment: @HannaHaddad  . . . You have the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to generate the query that gives me the desired number for a given date max. My problem is translating this into something that generates this number across all possible dates in one query

Don't just just want the date in the `group by` clause?

```
select dt, 
    sum(cumulative_plates_ordered) as cumulative_plates_ordered, 
    count(*) as number_of_people
from (
    select guest_id, 
        most_recent_plate_ordered_date::date as dt, 
        max(cumulative_plates_ordered) as cumulative_plates_ordered
    from raw_data
    group by 1,2
) t
group by dt
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to take in accounts "missing" dates, then it is a bit different. You can generate all possible combinations of days and guests with a `cross join`. Then use window functions to fill the gaps:

```
select dt, 
    sum(cumulative_plates_ordered) as cumulative_plates_ordered, 
    count(*) as number_of_people
from (
    select g.guest_id, d.dt,
        max(max(t.cumulative_plates_ordered)) over(order by d.dt) as cumulative_plates_ordered
    from (select distinct most_recent_plate_ordered_date::date as dt from raw_data) d
    cross join (select distinct guest_id from raw_data) g
    left join raw_data t
        on  t.guest_id = g.guest_id
        and t.most_recent_plate_ordered_date >= d.dt
        and t.most_recent_plate_ordered_date <  d.dt + interval 1 day
    group by g.guest_id, d.dt
) t
group by dt
```

Comment: In theory, if every possible date was included, yes this would work. The problem is that every possible date is not included. Using the example above, for guest_id = 1 on 10/3 the cumulative plates ordered is 2. However, that record does not exist in the data, meaning when you aggregate with the group by, there are 2 plates missing in the 10/3 row.

Comment: @HannaHaddad: that makes the question more interesting - but it was not obvious at all in your question. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm receiving the error "Error in SQL: table name "d" specified more than once." I'm not sure which reference I need to remove.

Comment: @HannaHaddad: my bad. Fixed.